# Automatically merge several collections to one

Tags: java, generics, collections, subclass, guava

I have some Guava `Functions` like `Function<String,Set<String>>`. Using those with `FluentIterable.transform()` leads to a `FluentIterable<Set<String>>`, however I need a `FluentIterable<String>`. So my idea now would be to subclass `FluentIterable<E>` and add a new method `transform2()` which simply merges everything to one collection before returning it.

The original transform method looks like this:

```
public final <T> FluentIterable<T> transform(Function<? super E, T> function) {
  return from(Iterables.transform(iterable, function));
}
```

I thought of something like this for my subclass and `transform2()` method:

```
public abstract class FluentIterable2<E> extends FluentIterable<E> 
{       
    public final <T> FluentIterable<T> transform2(Function<? super E, Collection<T>> function) {
        // (PROBLEM 1) Eclipse complains: The field FluentIterable<E>.iterable is not visible  
        Iterable<Collection<T>> iterables = Iterables.transform(iterable, function);

        // (PROBLEM 2) Collection<T> merged = new Collection<T>(); // I need a container / collection - which one?
        for(Collection<T> iterable : iterables)
        {
            // merged.addAll(iterable);
        }

        // return from(merged);
    }
}
```

Currently I have two problems with my new subclass, marked above with `PROBLEM 1` and `PROBLEM 2`

- PROBLEM 1: The iterable field in the original FluentIterable class is private - what can I do about this? Can I create a new private field with the same name in my subclass, will this then be OK? What about methods in my subclass that call super.someMethod() which uses this field? Will they then use the field of the super class, which probably has a different value?
- PROBLEM 2: I need some generic collection where I can combine the content of several collections, but collections is an interface, so I can't instantiate it. So, which class can I use there?

It would be acceptable if the solution only works with sets, though I'd prefer a solution that works with sets and lists.

Thanks for any hint on this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does `FluentIterable.transformAndConcat(stringToSetFunction)` not work for your use case?

Comment: This seems to do exacty what I was looking for, though even now I don't understand the documentation for this!?

Comment: What part of the documentation don't you understand?  If you tell us, maybe we can improve the docs.

Comment: It's to abstract in my opinion, when I read the method name or the javadoc "returns a fluent iterable with the concatenated combination of results" I think of concatenated strings. OK, now I notice that if you think of concatenating Iterables, it actually fits, maybe add sth. like "this means the collections returned by function are combined to one collection" or sth. like that, but probably it's really just my fault ;-)

Comment: @LouisWasserman A simple example is often worth its weight in gold...especially when a method signature is full of Generics Gobbledygook.

Answer (score 3):

Why subclass FluentIterable just to do this? You just need a simple loop:

```
Set<String> union = Sets.newHashSet();
for (Set<String> set : fluentIterableOfSets) {
    union.addAll(set);
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't always want to write this loop, also I want to chain several method calls (that's why I use FluentIterable), but the next transform functions I use expect only a collection, not a Collection of collections.

Answer (score 3):

Use `FluentIterable.transformAndConcat(f)`, where `f` is a Function mapping an element to some kind of iterable over the element type.

In your case, let's say your `Function<String, Set<String>>` is called TOKENIZE, and your initial `Iterable<String>` is called LINES.

Then to get a `Set<String>` holding all the distinct tokens in LINES, do this:

```
Iterable<String> LINES = ...;
Function<String, Set<String>> TOKENIZE = ...;
Set<String> TOKENS = FluentIterable.from(LINES)
    .transformAndConcat(TOKENIZE)
    .toSet();
```

But consider JB Nizet's answer carefully. Try it both ways and see which works better.

Comment: thank you for the complete example, nice for the archive. But why should one consider JB Nizet's answer carefully? Which possible problem do you see with the direct Guava way?

Comment: Read the Caveats section of this page for a full answer: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained